# DJANGO virtual env unable to import models when running a standalone script

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Trying to import django model in a standalone python script but i have a virtual env which might be the cause not sure

here's the pic[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF7Fq.png)

Here's the updated pic[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us4Cb.png)

Comment: As the error says, you should set an environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE (e.g. if you're on a linux/unix environment, put `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'myproject.settings'` in your shell config). Or use `python manage.py runserver --settings=myproject.settings`

Comment: I've tried that, but I'm just trying to run a script... it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: what script? If your script tries to access any of your django code, you can't run it without setting up django first, so your script should start with `settings.configure()`.

Comment: Then you should show that script and state exactly how you are running it.

Comment: have you added your app in the list INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file?

Comment: And you should probably write a django management command, see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: yes i've added it to installed_apps @RishiBansal

Comment: When i try settings.configure(), i get this error: 
@dirkgroten
`AttributeError: module 'foodBuddy.foodBuddy.settings' has no attribute 'configure'
`

Comment: It's `from django.conf import settings` the one that has `configure()`.

Comment: @dirkgroten i tried that but then i got this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
"/Users/husseinnagri/Desktop/Frontend_Learning/DjangoLearning/FoodBuddy/foodBuddy/food/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Food(models.Model):
"/Users/husseinnagri/Desktop/Frontend_Learning/DjangoLearning/FoodBuddy/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

Comment: [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) is what you should do. (i.e. after calling configure() also call django.setup())

Comment: @dirkgroten haha i tried that too :  
`RuntimeError: Model class foodBuddy.food.models.Food doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
`

Answer (score 1):

To use Django in a standalone script:

- Configure your settings by using `settings.configure()` or, much easier, set the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` before running your script.
- Call `django.setup()`

This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage).

Note that in many cases, writing a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-management-commands/) is easier and the better way do do things. It'll allow you to run `python manage.py mycommand` like other django commands.

Comment: `RuntimeError: Model class foodBuddy.food.models.Food doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

THis error still occurs

Comment: Any idea? @dirkgroten

Comment: You need to pass all your settings into the configure() function (at least the ones that your script will need, so you need to pass `INSTALLED_APPS` as parameter). Look at the link I published, scroll up to see how `settings.configure()` works.

Comment: I tried following the docs: 
`AttributeError: module 'foodBuddy.foodBuddy.settings' has no attribute 'LOGGING_CONFIG'
`

Comment: Please update your question by showing us your script with the current commands you're calling. This way it'll be easier to understand what you're doing. Or start a new question.

Comment: You should **not** override `default_settings` when calling `configure()`! If you do, you need to add all the settings from global_settings.py (in django/conf).

Comment: As I said, you're overriding `default_settings`, you shouldn't as this means the `global_settings` from Django aren't used and therefore something like `LOGGING_CONFIG` is missing. If you do just `settings.configure(DEBUG=True)` (mind the uppercase!) your script should work as it is now. But if you import a model and fetch something from the db, you'll need to do `settings.configure(DEBUG=True, INSTALLED_APPS=..., DATABASES=...)` passing all the required settings for the code following to work. Things like `MIDDLEWARE` or `TEMPLATES` aren't needed if your script doesn't run requests.

Comment: Just set the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE :-) So much easier.

Comment: I tried setting the environment variable, but not too sure where to set it?

Comment: BTW , `settings.configure(DEBUG=True)`. this doesnt fix the script unfortunately

Comment: Your script (with all the lines regarding `Food` commented out) should work with just `settings.configure()` because it doesn't do much that has to do with Django. As I said, if you import `Food`, you also need to pass `INSTALLED_APPS` and `DATABASES` and maybe more stuff depending on your code. To set your environment variable, it depends whether you're on linux/unix/macos or windows. In the former case, just add the `export` in your shell config (.bashrc or .zshrc or .profile or ... depending on your setup), in the latter case, google it.